# Internet explorer using wrong screen width for bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

**Edit: solved the problem, it was a missing brace in my media queries, which the validator didn't pick up.**

s the question says, internet explorer is showing the tablet version of my site, even in ie 10 and 11.

I have a psuedo element on the screen which shows which screen width is being used for testing purposes, and it shows 768px. ( small size for bootstrap ). In the same virtual box chrome shows the correct screen size.

Both html and css have been validated.

I'm assuming this to be a problem with my document head, but can't see anything wrong. This my head in full.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald%7CRaleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-4*****-****']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Comment: It seems that IE handles @media differently... See this article: http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/04/how-to-have-your-media-queries-and-eat-ie-too/

Comment: @ericbelldesigns I think those issues are only for ie versions below ie 9.  And I have respond.js and htmlshim loaded for those versions

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "all" to your media queries like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```